# How to automate a carousel slideshow

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a automated slideshow that will allow quotes to be displayed in intervals as the user loads the index.html. I have managed to get a manually controlled one working, however cannot automate it, however I can get it to bring a manually controlled one, but automating it seems to be another thing.

Here is the HTML of the slides

```
     <!-- Slideshow container -->
                <div id="slideshow-container">
    
                    <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
                    <div class="slide" onload="change()">
                        <q>I love you the more in that I believe you had liked me for my own sake and for nothing else</q>
                        <p class="author">- John Keats</p>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="slide">
                        <q>But man is not made for defeat. A man can be destroyed but not defeated.</q>
                        <p class="author">- Ernest Hemingway</p>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="slide">
                        <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
                        <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
                    </div>
    
    
                </div>
                <!-- Dots/bullets/indicators -->
                <div class="dot-container">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                </div>
```

I have been using [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) for the CSS of the carousel, however will be changing it once I have it automated in order to better suit the requirements

below is the js linked in the foot of the body so as to ensure it loads.

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
    change(slideIndex);
    
    function plusSlides(n)
    {
      if (n >= 2)
      {
        n = 1;
      }
      change(slideIndex += n);
    }
    
    function currentSlide(n) {
      change(slideIndex = n);
    }
    
    
    function change(n)
    {
      var i;
      var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    
    }
    
    window.setInterval(change, 1000)
    window.setInterval(plusSlides, 1100)
```

I have been using  [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) to try to get the function, however I haven't been doing to good of a job at it.

I thought it might be a good idea to use set interval twice to change the index value and recall the change function, however it didn't work.

I would love to know where I am going wrong here and how to get it to work in a more fluid motion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with a bootstrap carousel from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/#events seemed most appropriate

Answer (score 0):

i used javascript from 2000 to 2012 almost so i drop it for frameworks to gain time to other things i should pay attention.
if you have no ideea how to start quick with bootstrap you can experiment this program and you can drop and see in the browser the carousel you like

https://pingendo.com/
this is a what you see is what you get concept over jquery,html,css and bootstrap

there are other many there but with this one you can get quick results..before covid I got the license and I used to generate html templates for my php framework.

to more settings see bootstrap's websites